# Equation of plane that passes through point and is perpendicular to the certain line

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find the equation of plane that passes through the point $(5,2,1)$ and is perpendicular to the line $(x,y,z)=(4-t,1+2t,8-3t)$.

I don't know if I did this correct but this is what I have:
$$
PQ = ((4-5), (1-2), (8-1)) = <-1,-1,7>
$$
Giving that the equation equals to:

$x=-1-t, y-1+2t, z=7-3t$

Comment: The solution you have is the equation of a line, not a plane.

Comment: oh okay, so find n by solving for t=1 which would be P(3,3,5) then n= (3-4),(3-1),(5-8) = <-1,2,-3> then plug into the formula Ax+By+Cz=n*Po then plane would be -x+2y-3z=-4?